# Why `Merge Queries as new` by INNER JOIN cannot detect matching rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

The goal is to limit `CompanyName` in a slicer, to make it only matching to `Fact_Premium` dataset.

I've done exactly the same thing in copy of the report and it worked. But for some reason it doesn't work now.

`Merge as new` is unable to detect matching `CompanyLocationGUID` columns between table `Dim_Companies` and `Fact_Premium`.

[image]

Her is the prove that at least 1 record have to match:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the IDs in DimCompany have letters lower case, and in FactPremium upper case. Could you case this in the Query Editor (Text.Upper()), and let me know the result?

Comment: You were correct. I thought about that at first, but couldn't even think this can be an issue. 
Thanks. Post answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the IDs in DimCompany have letters lowercase and in FactPremium they're uppercase. Make sure they are the same.

You can change this in Query Editor:

```
Text.Upper([TEXT])
```

OR

```
Text.Lower([TEXT])
```